# How to react to fail response from server in React component if I need to setState after it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of elements, each of them I can delete by clicking on them (click fires the call to the server, which sends back new list, without the deleted item).

But I need to visually delete them from the view before the response from the server arrives.

I do it like this

```
state = {
        items: this.props.items,
        deletedItem: null
    };

onClickDelete = (item) => {
        const {items} = this.state;
        const itemsCopy = {...items};

        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(itemsCopy)) {
            if (value.id === tag.id) {
                delete itemsCopy[key];
                this.setState({
                    items: itemsCopy,
                    deletedItem: value
                });
            }
        }

        reduxActions(item)
    };
```

So that is happening:

My initial items are from props. When I click on the item I filter it out of state ( this way the item disappears from the view right away). Then I send action which performs a request to the server.

But is that the request to the server can return with an error. In that case, I want to return the deleted item to the state, so it will appear again.

Initially, I thought to create a flag in my Redux state, like `itemDeleted: true`. In case of successful request it stays `true`, in case of an error - it becomes `false`.

The problem as follows:

To react and redraw the component, adding an item, I'm doing something like this in my render method

```
if (!itemDeleted && !!deletedItem) { this.returnOnError(); }
```

And the function is

```
returnOnError= (): void => {
        const { deletedItem } = this.state;

        this.setState(prevState => ({
            items: {
                ...prevState.items,
                [deletedItem.id]: deletedItem
            }
        }));
    };
```

This causes two issues - one is that I'm calling `setState` in the render. Another is that when I click an item with error - the property `itemDeleted` becomes false and if I click again and get error again, the `itemDeleted` is already false so `returnOnError` fires anyway, without waiting for the result from the server.

I kind of lost there, all the help will be appreciated.
The only restriction is that I need to delete the item before getting a response from the server.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand the question. You basically need a flag in the displayed items (so you could add that flag to the objects in the list, or have an object with the object and a flag) to decide whether to display (and maybe a string message to reflect the type of error). If the call comes back with an error you then mark it as displayable. All render should do is display/not-display.

Comment: Allan did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called "optimistic UI updates".

1-) Before deleting an item,  save the original items.

2-) Update the UI immediately without waiting api call.

3-) In case of api error, recover the original items back.

You can try something like this:

```
handleDelete = async item => {
  /* store the current state in previousItems, just in case of server side fail */
  const previousItems = this.state.items;

  /* optimistically update on react side */
  const items = this.state.items.filter(p => p.id !== item.id);
  this.setState({ items });

  /*  If server side fail, rollback the state */
  try {
    await axios.delete(apiEndpoint + "/" + item.id);
  } catch (e) {
    this.setState({ items: previousItems });
  }
};
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-react-redux-optimistic-updates-8clj8) is a sample working codesandbox using react-redux to illustrate this.